# looking for a proof or a reference of classical result

Tags: category-theory, differential-forms, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, d-modules

Let $X$ be a complex manifold of dimension $n$, $\Omega_{X}$ the sheaf of top degree forms, $\mathcal{D}_{X}$ the sheaf of holomorphic differential operators of infinite order and $q$ the natural projection of $X\times X$ to $X$. It seems to be known that $\mathcal{D}_{X}\simeq H^{n}_{\Delta_{X}}(q^{-1}\Omega_{X}\otimes_{q^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X}}\mathcal{O}_{X\times X})$.

Is there any good reference of this ?

Comment: Just a suggestion: if you tell where you found this result, it might be easier to find the reference you need

Comment: @YuriyS Kashiwara-Shapira, "Sheaves on Manifold", definition 11.4.2, however this is stated in a more general context of micro-differential operators